# Kiali Bookinfo example is not showing traffic to rating and other microservices

Tags: istio, traffic, minishift, kiali

I'm  running the latest istio version on minishift. I can access the product page on http://192.168.178.102:31380/productpage.

Kiali is showing the traffic from istio-ingressgateway to productpage

[Kiali Traffic pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YwU5.jpg)

I expect to see some traffic from productpage to the other microservices but it does not show it.
Do you have any idea why?

These are my installation steps:

Minishift:

- minishift config set hyperv-virtual-switch "External VM Switch"
- minishift config set memory 8GB
- minishift config set image-caching true
- minishift config set cpus 4
- minishift addon enable anyuid
- minishift addon apply istio
- minishift addon enable istio
- minishift start

Book-info:

- kubectl create namespace book-info
- oc login -u system:admin
- kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=book-info
- kubectl label namespace book-info istio-injection=enabled
- kubectl apply -f samples\bookinfo\platform\kube\bookinfo.YAML
- kubectl get services
- kubectl apply -f samples\bookinfo\networking\bookinfo-gateway.YAML
- kubectl apply -f samples\bookinfo\networking\destination-rule-all.YAML

Thanks

any feedback is greatly appreciated.